# admin request user data from api

Tags: node.js, api, rest, security, permissions

I have a resource `/transactions/history` which is protected with JWT implementation. When a user sends a `get` request, their id is extracted from their token and their transactions data is retrieved. The problem I'm having is when the admin makes a `get` request to retrieve that particular user's transaction history without passing the user id as a param.
`con:` If i have to pass the user id for admin, it will be redundant for user as their id is in their token.

The other implementation I have for the admin is this;
all transaction user creates has it's id stored in an array in the user document, so admin will first fetch user's information and then fetch each transaction using their id using a `promise.all`  call.
`con`: this might slow down the retrieval process.

What is the best practice for this implementation as I want to keep it as secure and non redundant as possible

Comment: I suggest having a different route for the admin to access their own version of  /transaction/history, and then you could pass the user id as a param. Having a different route for the admin makes it easier for you since you can apply a middleware for different security measures.

Comment: Okay, that is quite redundant but a fail safe implementation after all. Thank you for your reply.